# Krypton Form not showing up in Visual Studio Professional 2008

Tags: visual-studio, krypton-toolkit

I have just installed the Krypton Toolkit 3.0.6 from component Factory.
I find that in the create new Project Dialog Box , Krypton Form does not show up as an option. I am sure it used to show up ( and I have actually used it in an earlier version of krypton toolkit).But after the new install it does not.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness and accuracy , I am posting the actual code for inheriting from a krypton form.

```
public partial class Form1  : ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonForm
```

Answer (score 1):

The "New Krypton Form" used to show up not inside the "new project" dialog, but inside the "new item" dialog. (e.g. right-click on project, Add New Item)

But I don't see it there either. Phil may have removed this from the installer.

In any case, just add a regular Form, then make it derive from KryptonForm rather than Form, and voila, you have yourself a KryptonForm.